# How can I set up an equation for distance traveled for a rubber band powered car?

Tags: energy, torque, rotation, distance

I am to make a rubber band powered car, and I have to maximize it's distance traveled. The time taken to reach said distance, top speed of the car, acceleration of the car, is not relevant. I just want to maximize distance.

What would be the easiest way to go about this? I am thinking I could either take the route of Torque ($T=Fr=Ia$), where I would break up inertia into the axle and both wheels on each side. Or I could take the route of energy ($\frac 1 2 kx^2 = \frac 1 2 mv^2 = \text{work}$?).

I'm very confused by this as there are so many things involved. Any clarification and help would be appreciated.

Comment: Without friction that distance is infinite.

Comment: Hi, the equation I form should help me decide on the size of wheels for my car in real life, so i suppose I will have to account for friction. Again, im not sure how to do that.

Comment: Large, thin, extremely lightweight wheels and slow motion sound like a good idea, the rest is probably left to experiments.

Comment: Yeah but I'm meant to show equations. Could you please throw some equations at me that support the idea that slow motion (perhaps by having large wheels and large inertia) is beneficial for distance traveled?

Comment: The slow motion is to minimize air resistance... and that's hard to do with equations. The other question is... what's the road like? Are you racing on something hard and smooth?

Comment: it will be a smooth road.

Comment: Unless you have really accurate models for friction, your best bet is probably to try a few different values.

Answer (score 1):

You want to consider the following factors:

1. Maximize initial energy stored in the rubber band. This means you need to be able to twist the band lots of times, and as it unwinds it must continue to produce torque.
2. Minimize internal friction - make the mechanism that converts power from the band to kinetic energy as "direct" as possible. In fact a rubber band untwisting can lose a lot of energy; so would any gearing mechanism
3. Minimize air drag: drag goes as $$F = \frac12 \rho A C_D v^2$$ where $\rho$ is the air density (about 1.2 kg/m<sup>3</sup>), $A$ is the apparent area (looking at the front of the car), $C_D$ is the drag coefficient (about 0.5 for a sphere, smaller for a more aerodynamic car), and $v$ is the velocity. This is why a lower average velocity will help you - but how do you persuade the car to move slowly without a gearing mechanism... (see point 2 above!)
4. Minimize road friction. Rubber tires (especially not well inflated ones) will add to drag; hard wheels work better (which is why trains are so efficient), and large wheels work better (they ride over the surface without "digging a hole" for themselves).

Now in order to keep the maximum velocity low, you want a car that is as heavy as possible, with large low-friction wheels. Being heavy, it will prevent the car from initially going very fast - while storing all the energy from the elastic band as low velocity kinetic energy; this keeps the air drag down. But you need excellent wheels and a hard smooth surface (point 4) in order to make it so the heavy car doesn't suffer from rolling friction.

So you need to experiment. If the rolling friction can be modeled as $F_r = m g \mu_1$ and the air friction as $F_d = \alpha (\frac12 m v^2)/m$, you can see that for the same kinetic energy $\frac12 m v^2$ you will get lower air drag but higher rolling friction as you increase $m$.

This means that if you play around with the mass, you will find there is an optimum: either very light, or very heavy, cars will not work as well as the ones that are "just right".

Goldilocks. Every time.

Comment: I mostly agree, but making the car heavy will increase rolling resistance and it will not limit the velocity but only the initial acceleration. What he really needs to do is to build a low friction mechanism to match the large torque in the rubber band to the low torque required to move a light car slowly. To be honest... it almost sounds like a problem that can be solved with an escapement better than with mass. Having said that, construction of an efficient escapement mechanism is neither easy nor much fun, but I can imagine that it could get a mile or more out of a fairly small (1m) car.

Comment: We arent expected to think about drag or internal friction. So ignoring these things what are the pros and cons of small/ large wheels in terms of energy/force/torque. Thankyou for your response

Comment: @CuriousOne you state "making the car heavy ... Will not limit the velocity". But a large mass _does_ limit the top speed - simple kinetic energy argument. $v_{max}=\sqrt{\frac{2E}{m}}$ - larger mass, lower velocity for same energy in spring. Complex mechanisms add more friction...

Comment: If you make the car so heavy that all potential energy in the rubber band is converted to kinetic energy (which is not even possible with a simple design), then you have definitely made the car too heavy. From an engineering point of view I would suggest that over 50% of the mass of the car should be in the rubber band for a design that is even borderline optimal.